# Mark up for info/warning/error messages

Tags: discussion, markup

Following on from the discussion about [block quotes and text starting with `!`](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/), I think it might be a good idea to look at how best to format messages, *etc*. For actual TeX code, life is clear enough (mark up as code), but for messages from software we can either use code mark up (as it's terminal output) or blockquote mark up (as it is something 'said' by the software). To date, I've always marked up messages as code, but obviously this is not true of everyone. How do other people see this: is there a consensus for one or other approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a good idea to use code blocks. I can't find the example any more, but once I changed a blockquote to a code block where something like this happened:

> LaTeX Error: File `articl.cls' not found.
>   blah blah`something else' with quotes `' around it.

This looks very bad in a blockquote; it's supposed to look like this:

```
LaTeX Error: File `articl.cls' not found.
blah blah `something else' with quotes `' around it.
```

Comment: Also any white space vanishes.

Comment: I agree that it *should* be in code blocks.  The point, as I see it, of the other discussion is that for a new user, it's not obvious and so the software should still display something sensible when it is put in a blockquote.

Comment: @Andrew: I couldn't agree more.